# Led Strip switches

Tags: switches, led-strip

Good day everyone. I am not a pro electrician, I am just a student who wants something new in our house. I hope that you can help me with this. And this will be much appreciated.

I want to put led strips in our kitchen and to have switches on it. But I do not know where exactly I should put it, is it between the transformer and 220 volt power supply? or between the transformer and the lights?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put it between the transformer and the light, the transformer will be contineously consume power.
Therefore, I'd advise to put it between this 220V power supply and the transformer.
Make sure the switch satisfies the voltage and current rating.